# Inline PHP Tag not closing

Tags: php, html, css

I have included php in html to change the background image according to some variables. Thus i am calling `img-set()` function in body tag. The function is working fine. But the html code breaks after the function has been run. I think it's some syntax problem not able to it figure out.

```
<body style="background:url(images/<?php $obj->set_img();?>); -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;">
```

The output in source code of web browser looks like:

```
<body style="background:url(images/music7.jpg
```

This break after displaying image name. Why so ??

Here, is the set_img() function

```
function set_img()
{
$ctr = date("d");
$arr7 = array("7","18","29");
$status = 0;

foreach($arr7 as $value){
if($ctr == $value){
echo "music7.jpg";
$status = 7;
}}
if(!$status) echo "music1.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Are you displaying your PHP errors?

Comment: Can you include to body of `set_img()` function?

Comment: From the code, you are providing, it liiks that something is wrong with the object, but `error log` is needed to see, to know what exactly.

Comment: if you are put this $obj->set_img() in .html it's wrong! Or try var_dump($obj->set_img()) and post here result

Comment: @RadikCH depends how your server is set up. If it's set up to render .html with PHP (which is often done to hide the used technology for security reasons) there is nothing wrong about it.

Comment: acme yes you are right))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<?php set_img();?>` not `<?php $obj->set_img();?>`

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a problem with your set_img() function causing the rest of the page to stop rendering.  Look at the code after you output the image.  A quick test to see if the error is due to your function is to remove that php block and see if the page renders fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style="background:url(images/<?php set_img();?>); -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an unrendered exception too.

But when I watch the set_img function, I cannot imagine how it could throw any exception. 
May be $obj is not instanciate with the right class ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a silent PHP error. It can be difficult to detect sometimes. Try checking your Apache error logs at `/var/log/Apache2` and it should say what error is causing PHP to break.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be missing quotes around your url. Try:

```
<body style="background:url('imges/music7.jpg')">
```

Comment: I wasn't saying the double quote, but rather the inside url which did not have any quote around it. From my experience with working with CSS, the url inside the () has been single-quoted. This code does not have that.

Comment: **@Gene Parmesan** Quotes are optional.

Comment: Quotes inside `url()` are entirely optional (and single quotes actually broke the old IE/Mac).

Comment: @Florent No problem, we're all just here to help out.